# Using MASM with VS2013 failed (error MSB3721 / exit code 1)

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2013, zlib, masm

I tried to compile assembly code via Visual Studio 2013 (Update 2) and I received the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(50,5): error MSB3721: Der Befehl "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\inffas32.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta"......\3rdParty\zlib-1.2.8\contrib\masmx86\inffas32.asm"" wurde mit Code 1 beendet.

(a German VS2013 version, indeed, but should be no problem for this question I believe)

In fact I try to compile the zLib 1.2.8 MASM contributions via VS2013. I created an empty project, did the build customization for MASM, added the two files (inffas32.asm and match686.asm) from the zLib package.
I changed the project to create a static lib and set the sub-system to windows.
But I received the error message above.

If I try to compile to compile a file manually in a VS2013 shell with this command line all is working well.

The above procedure worked well in VS2012 - but now, in VS2013 it will not be compiled anymore (even if I open the VS2012 project).

Did I miss something, or is it a bug in the MASM customization build?

Comment: Look in the Output window for additional diagnostic message(s).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this problem on my own which might help others, too:

Compiling the code produces a A5000 warning because of some .FPO directive in the assembly code. This warning will force ml.exe to exit for a warning level higher than 1.

If I reduce the warning level to 1 or 0 this warning will not appear and all is working.

If someone know how to disable this "treat warning as error" let me know. The project setting of this feature is NOT working for me.
Anyway no warning, no error and .FPO just controls the emission of debug records. So, the pure code is fine I believe (commenting this line out would be fine, too).

@Hans Passant: The diagnostic output does not help. I did took a look at it before your tipp, but thanks for your time and having a look at my problem! :)

Comment: I was building zlib as well though as CMake External Project. One may consider adding `-DAMD64=ON -DASM686=ON "-DCMAKE_ASM_MASM_FLAGS=/W0 /safeseh"` to CMAKE_ARGS of External_Project_Add.